# jetpack compose and MotionLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout

Regarding MotionLayout I have few questions.

- First How can we update custom properties. I have read the docs, but their is no way to animate the custom properties with non-jason constraint set.
- Second, Since compose recommands using lambdas version of function for animation but motion layout takes progress ht
- Third, the progress param which I Pass to MotionLayout is required in child composables; is it good to use this with them or MotionLayout provides any other way.
- Suppose I have a function that doesn't have lambda version and I have to animate its some Modifier property like scale; would it be good to use Modifier.composed {} lamda to animate it. Will it perform better.